# Can an html button launch a different A HREF when held down?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is it possible to make one html button launch different a href?

For example: if you press the button it launches w3schools.com but if you hold it down it launches google.com instead.

I'm looking for it to work in a web app on a mobile phone, and am thinking it might be doable with the jQuery taphold Event.

Or in other words:

```
<button><a href="sms:?&body=https://www.google.com">Try Me</a></button>
```

if pressed and

```
<button><a href="https://www.google.com">Try Me</a></button>
```

if held.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Did you write the code to put the url in the text message body?

Comment: @cham I made it from answers I found on here a while back. Works fine, but just interested to see if it can be changed on the fly. Maybe using right click stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tap` and `taphold` event you can achieve your desired result.

> `pagecreate` event is fired when HTML is created in DOM

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $.event.special.tap.emitTapOnTaphold = false;
    $("button").on('tap',function(){
        console.log('tap!');
    }).on('taphold',function(){
        console.log('taphold!');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<button>Hit me</button>
```

> - Just replace the `console.log` line with `window.open('URL')` and you are done.
> - `$.event.special.tap.emitTapOnTaphold = false;` is used to disable the default click event when you tap and hold the button.

Comment: You are a star! Nice one for seeing beyond the wording of the question and taking the time to provide some much need / appreciated help.

Comment: Thank you @PofK. Happy to help. :)